# Should I create a separate table that has the same structure as an existing table given that the new table will serve an entirely different purpose?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, datatables, architecture

I have an email table for emails that go to one subset of users. I want to create another email table for emails that go to a completely different subset of users. However, since I have an existing table that has the same exact structure, should I just re-use that table? Is there an architectural advantage of creating a separate table because it serves a different purpose?

Edit: As a note, all columns on both tables will be filled. There aren't different types associated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: Not exactly, all columns would be filled.

Comment: [Are tables with the same attributes but different relationships bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33066601/3404097) PS Try to avoid rhetorical questions & clearly ask 1 question. Please don't ask what's "best" or what you "should do" We can't decide for you. There's no "better"/"best" in engineering unless you define it. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask 1 very specific question. [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461/266284)

Comment: The first suggested link is about representing subtyping/inheritance in DBs/SQL and yours is a special case. But you really need to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. Otherwise you are just constantly coming up on things you have no way to deal with & are asking us to rewrite one & haven't done appropriate research. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.) Ask where you are stuck *following a method*. Q&A can't educate.

Comment: [Turn two database tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24761568/3404097) PS  Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: There is no advantage in creating the second table

Comment: It would be useful if you were a bit more explicit about what purpose the two different types of emails serves, as well naming the subsets of users. This makes it easier for others to write an answer that is relevant to your situation.